# removing items from an azure queue with a visibility delay

Tags: c#, azure, azure-queues

Im placing items into an azure queue with a visibiliy delay. These items 'popup' at the appropriate time and are processed by a webjob.

The process works perfectly.  However, my users now want the ability to edit data that is associated with an item that is currently in a queue with a visibility delay.  How do I remove this item from the queue so that my users can edit its asocited detail, save it to an underlying database, then place it back in the queue once its been edited sand saved ?

I have a mechanism in place to allow the editing of this data from a database, which will then efectively create a new instance of my message and place it in the queue. the problem is that I then have effectively 2 messages in the queue for the same item, so i want to be able to delete the original when users begin the editing process.  So how do I pull the original message from the queue If I cant see it because of its visibility delay ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using storage queues and not Service Bus. Try using the `UpdateMessage` method.

```
q.UpdateMessage(message, visbility, MessageUpdateFields.Content | MessageUpdateFields.Visibility);
```

I'll have a look at it shortly and update you if that has changed from the last time I worked with storage queues.